# Counting arguments in parser.y?

Tags: c, parsing, bison

Is there a way to count arguments in the parser.y? I'm trying something that is recursive and I feel like that may not work due to the way yyparse() works. Here's what I'm trying in my parser.y:

```
arg_list:
     | arg ',' arg_list { 
          int func_arg_list_count(){ int argCount = 0; return argCount+1; }
```

**

*EDIT*

**: Some updates, the above code is wrong as pointed out to me. Here is my union with some suggestions to update though I'm still having issues with the $1.

```
%union {
int val;
int count;
char *funcName;
}

%token <funcName> ID

%type <val> exp prop
%type <count> arg_list
```

Is it become my semantic value in lexer.l does not match up?

Oh here is there error code:

```
error: $1 of ‘arg_list’ has no declared type
 | arg ',' arg_list { $$ = $1 + 1; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is written in the OP won't compile. In C, a function definition can only appear at the top-level, not inside braces, and bison actions are not at the top-level. (They are inside of a case statement, and in any event, the individual actions retain their braces.)

In bison, every non-terminal (and every terminal, for that matter) has a semantic value with a type specific to the non-terminal. So if you want the `arg_list`'s semantic type to include the argument count, there is no problem. Just declare an appropriate type and add it to your `%union`. As a really simple example, here's an `arg_list` whose semantic type is precisely the count of arguments: (*edited*, @ChrisDodd pointed out the flaw in the original)

```
%union {
   int count;
   /* other types */
}

%type <count> arg_list non_empty_arg_list

%%

arg_list: /* EMPTY */        { $$ = 0; /* An empty list has no arguments */ }
        | non_empty_arg_list { $$ = $1; /* This is the default action. */ }

non_empty_arg_list:
          arg                        { $$ = 1; /* Starts with one argument */ }
        | non_empty_arg_list ',' arg { $$ = $1 + 1; /* Now it has one more argument */ }
        ;
```

Normally the semantic action of the arg_list would also build up a list of arguments in some fashion, so the semantic value would typically be more complicated. But that's a basic outline.

Comment: So, I have a union that has int val; and char *funcName, should I just add count?

Comment: @pmac89: That depends 100% on what you actually need as a semantic value for your arg_list non-terminal. You don't need to use a separate tag if you already have an appropriate type in your union, either; it's totally up to you.

Comment: So, that helped solve that issue and completely makes sense. I've updated my code above, is my thinking correct? I just need the $#?

Comment: @pmac: `$1` is the first symbol in the rhs of the production. If you change the right-hand side, you need to change the index as well.

Comment: Do I need the count in another union for arg_list? Cause I also have it for %token <funcName> ID

%type <val> exp prop

Comment: @pmac89: It's just an ordinary C union, no magic added. You don't need two members with the same type and different names, no. (The only reasons to do that would be for documentation or in case you thought you might want to change one of the types later, although that's not a very strong reason.)

Comment: Ok. So just use the %type <val> and just add arg_list? EDIT: That didn't fix it either.

Comment: @pmac89: Sure, that's fine. Until you decide an arg_list has to include its arguments :)

Comment: So, I'm still getting the $1 error even when I do that. Right now, arg_list does not need to hold the arguments just cause I'm just trying to figure out how to get the number of arguments to match up with the definition to the calls.

Comment: As written, this grammar requires a comma before the first argument.  The right recursive version from the OP requires a comma after the last argument.  You want `arg_list: arg {$$=1;} | arg_list ',' arg {$$=$1+1;}`

Comment: Please look closely at my code and my comment about $1. If in doubt, reread the bison documentation about what `$n` means. (And think about why you've chosen to use right recursion in that production. Its certainly legal, but its not very common because it eats parsing stack space.)

Comment: @ChrisDodd: well spotted. Fixing.